# path to image folder on server

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a wordpress inside Public html folder on server.

i want to dispaly images from the folder Public_html--->Trial-->Wordpress_site-->uploads

below is page.php code

```
           <?php

    $directory = dirname(__FILE__).'/uploads'; 

                        echo $directory;
                        try {    
                            // Styling for images

                            foreach ( new DirectoryIterator("/" . $directory) as $item ) {          
                                if ($item->isFile()) {

                                    echo "<div class=\"expand_image\">";
                                    $path = "/" . $directory . "/" . $item;
                                    echo $path;
                                    echo "<img src=/"". $path . "\" width=861 height=443  />";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception $e) {
echo 'No images found for this player.<br />';
   }


     ?>
```

The images arent getting displayed..

anyone knows about the same??

**edit1**

I think there is problem in this sentence

```
  echo "<img src=/"". $path . "\" width=861 height=443  />";
```

is it?

**edit2**

//home/softwar2/public_html/Pradnnya_blog/wordpress_site/wp-content/themes/deep-red/our_results/4thpanelfinal.jpg

is the path that i get when echoed.

Comment: What is the exact problem you see? Do you get the 'No images found for this player.' string, do you get the echoed $path variable, if you open the page source, are you missing the div tags, or do you get nothing at all?

Comment: i get the path as follows

//home/softwar2/public_html/Pradnnya_blog/wordpress_site/wp-content/themes/deep-red/our_results/4thpanelfinal.jpg

but image isnt displayed

Answer (score 1):

[`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) gives you the path of the current file on the filesystem; however, when you visit the webpage and you see a link in the  tag, you'll try to access that as a URL instead of a file. For this, you might find `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` useful, or another one of the [$_SERVER elements](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). It might be better to have the URL in a configuration file though, because $_SERVER may sometimes not be set.

Answer (score 0):

Good catch, there's a bit of a syntax error:

```
echo "<img src=\"". $path . "\" width=861 height=443  />";
```

You'll want to use the backslash to escape the double quote.

Comment: @pradnya Try `$path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/Pradnnya_blog/wordpress_site/wp-content/themes/deep-‌​red/our_results/' . $item;` for now to see if the outputted `$path` variable can be copied and pasted into the URL bar of the browser, and will return an image. Basically, you want to manipulate it so the printed `$path` address can resolve to an actual image.

Comment: hi ..i get following ...http://sever_url.com/Pradnnya_blog/wordpress_site/wp-content/themes/deep-red/our_results/6thpanelfinal.jpg

if the same i put in navigation bar image isnt displayed